# Error while inserting data into a HIVE table

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, hdfs, bigdata

I am trying to insert some data from a 'tab delimited file' into a HIVE table which has been created already. I have created 4 basic columns in the HIVE table named 'users'. I am using the following command:

```
load data local inpath 'D:\users.txt'
into table users;
```

I get the following error message after running the above command:

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10028]: Line 1:23 Path is not legal ''D:\users.txt'': Source file system should be "file" if "local" is specified
```

I am using Windows 7 and running HIVE on Amazon Web Services via PUTTY.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

TIA

Comment: i am not sure how this works in windows.. but it looks like you have to give file:///D://users.txt

Comment: sonic is right: java works with '/' as a file delimiter, not windoes-like '\'

Comment: anyway you can not load the file directly from your local computer to hive on AWS. local keyword means locally on the server running hive versus file from hdfs.  copy the file to the server (using winscp for example) and then issue the load command with the local path in the server

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I had to copy the code to the server and the code worked. Although, while inserting the values from the text file, the table in HIVE only takes all NULL values. Any idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally, if someone is trying to add values to a table from a tab delimited text file, the following command should work:

```
hive> create table test_table(k string, v string) row format delimited fields terminated by '\t' stored as textfile;
```

Comment: The above command will work after the tab-delimited file has been copied on to the server. I did this using WinSCP.